# Why do I get this error when running update.php?

Tags: 8, updating

Attempting to update drupal 8.0 to 8.1, when I run update.php, I receive this error:

> An AJAX HTTP error occurred.
>   HTTP Result Code: 500
>   Debugging information follows.
>
> Path: /update.php/start?id=88&op=do_nojs&op=do
>   StatusText: Internal Server Error

The error log contains the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher::getListenerPriority() in /var/www/html/vendor/symfony/event-dispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php on line 107, referer: http://example.com/update.php

Why do I get this error when running update.php?

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know what the issue was, but i got around it.

I was attempting to manually update drupal 8.0 to 8.1.

My update steps:

- Backed up database
- Backed up files
- Deleted core directory
- Deleted the vendor directory
- Deleted all files except the ones I added to the top directory
- Uploaded new files
- Uploaded new 8.1 core directory
- Uploaded new 8.1 vendor directory
- Ran update.php

My fix.

- Restored my sites files and database
- Installed Drush 9 (Check your permissions
- Ran pm-update
- Boom success

Anyways still curious on why the ajax error. My guess would be it was a permission issue.

Comment: You should also run drush entup, there may be entity schema changes that are needed.